# Push data to a webpage from sql

Tags: sql, websocket

Can I use sql to send data to a browser using html5 web sockets? What I want to do is have a browser subscribe to a set of data and push that data to the browser when there is a change to the data.

Or maybe post that data to a server page that will then push it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL standard (AFAIK) doesn't have anything in it that would allow SQL to push notifications out.

Some RDBMS implementations do have something that would allow something like this (although whether it'd work with WebSockets is another question, and the answer is: probably not easily).  For example, SQL Server has Service Broker, which offers some functionality around setting up queues that could be subscribed to - SQL Server then internally handles polling and publishing.  I'm sure Oracle has some similar capabilities using queues/topics and JMS.

I would avoid using that kind of technology though - it tends to not always work exactly as desired and require customization anyway.  Or rather, you should abstract this functionality into a web service, which would either do its own polling of SQL or use one of those built-in functionalities to then use a WebSocket type of communication back to your HTML5 page.